# If I create a template class, than other classes where I send reference (pointer) to that class must be templated?

Tags: c++, templates

Let say I've [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56ad02de915b0892) with a EnvelopeMultiPoints class `template`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
    // base
};

template<class T>
class EnvelopeMultiPoints : public EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
public:
    static unsigned int mNumPoints;

    EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }
    ~EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }

    void Process() {
        std::cout << "process: " << mNumPoints << std::endl;
    }
};

class Pitch : public EnvelopeMultiPoints<Pitch> { };

template<typename T>
unsigned int EnvelopeMultiPoints<T>::mNumPoints = 5;

class Container
{
public:
    EnvelopeMultiPointsBase *pAssociatedEnvelope;

    Container(EnvelopeMultiPointsBase *associatedEnvelope) : pAssociatedEnvelope(associatedEnvelope) { }
    ~Container() { }

    void Process();

private:
};

int main()
{
    EnvelopeMultiPoints<Pitch> pitch;
    Container container(&pitch);
    container.pAssociatedEnvelope->Process();
}
```

And I want to pass to the `Container` any kind of "EnvelopeMultiPoints" types (a generic "pointer"), so later I can access to its own method (in my case, `Process()`).

Does it means that also `Container` must be `templated`? (which is huge in my real scenario; lot of works to transform all of its methods in template, translate header/cpp, and such).

Or is there a trick that I'm missing?

In few words: let say that I want to pass to `Container` `EnvelopeMultiPoints<Pitch>`, and than execute `Process()`. Later, I want to pass `EnvelopeMultiPoints<Volume>` instead, and than execute `Process()`. And so on. Is there a way to do this without converting also `Container` to a template?

Comment: Well, you already doing it in a way that works("Correct": is a subjective term here).... `Container` objects can be constructed with any object of `EnvelopeMultiPointsBase*` or its derivatives. And every instantiation of the *class-template* `EnvelopeMultiPoints<T>` is a derivative of `EnvelopeMultiPointsBase`... Just make sure you are overriding your **`virtual`** functions appropriately. What do you mean about changing `Container` from a *class* to a *class-template*?

Comment: Specific for this issue: you could make process a virtual function in EnvelopeMultiPointsBase.

Comment: @stefaanv: nope. `Process()` use variables of `EnvelopeMultiPoints` (which are not known within `EnvelopeMultiPointsBase`).

Comment: @paizza - And? Dynamic binding is exactly how we get around such issues. You really should check out the examples bellow.

Comment: In order to call his "own function" (non virtual), you must "provide" the type (`EnvelopeMultiPoints<Pitch>`). You can dynamic_cast it, use boost::any or boost::variant. But however, once the type is lost(because of derived to base conversion or convert to void * etc.), you must provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you need is called [dynamic polymorphism](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Polymorphism)
that is implemented in C++ by [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Illustrating using your code:

```
class EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
public:

    // Abstract base, no actual implementation
    virtual void Process() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class EnvelopeMultiPoints : public EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
public:
    static unsigned int mNumPoints;

    EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }
    ~EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }

    // Some specific implementation.
    virtual void Process() override
    {
        std::cout << "process: " << mNumPoints << std::endl;
    }
};

class Pitch : public EnvelopeMultiPoints<Pitch>
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To call the `Process` function of the base class, you have to define it in the base class. You can move the implementation to templated child classes:

```
class EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
    private:
    virtual void ProcessImpl() = 0;

    public:
    void Process() {
        //potential common code...
        ProcessImpl();
        //more potential common code...
    }
};

template<class T>
class EnvelopeMultiPoints : public EnvelopeMultiPointsBase
{
public:
    static unsigned int mNumPoints;

    EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }
    ~EnvelopeMultiPoints() { }

    private:
    void ProcessImpl() {
        std::cout << "process" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: In this particular case, there is no reason not to write just `virtual void Process() = 0;` in `EnvelopeMultiPointsBase`.  If there is some processing that is common to all, then this non-virtual public + protected virtual can be useful.

Comment: Any reasons why `ProcessImpl()` are not private in both cases? It's not like they should be used externally.

Comment: @MartinBonner I agree, don't know why I overcomplicated this. Won't edit it now, as Rost's answer does just that

Comment: @stefaanv I agree as well, edited. I tend to prefer protected members, but this is clearer now, in the derived class it was just an oversight